# ATmega328P not responding

Tags: atmega, avrdude

All of the sudden my ATmega328P stopped responding to flash commands with avrdude.
Here is the output of the attempt:

```
avrdude -pm328p -P/dev/parport0 -cstk200 -v -F -Uflash:w:./bin/main.hex:i

avrdude: Version 5.11.1, compiled on Oct 30 2011 at 10:41:10
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/home/darkhan/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/parport0
         Using Programmer              : stk200
         AVR Part                      : ATMEGA328P
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PC2
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : PPI
         Description     : STK200
           VCC     =  (not used)
           BUFF    = 4,5
           RESET   = 9
           SCK     = 6
           MOSI    = 7
           MISO    = 10
           ERR LED = 0
           RDY LED = 0
           PGM LED = 0
           VFY LED = 0

avrdude: AVR device not responding
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions
avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000
avrdude: Yikes!  Invalid device signature.
avrdude: Expected signature for ATMEGA328P is 1E 95 0F
avrdude: NOTE: FLASH memory has been specified, an erase cycle will be performed
         To disable this feature, specify the -D option.

avrdude done.  Thank you.

make: *** [program] Error 1
```

I've used this micro for more than 1 year. But I don't think I've depleted its 10000 flash write/erase cycle count.

Last thing I've done was re-programming fuse with Reset Disable programmed:

```
avrdude -pm328p -P/dev/parport0 -cstk200 -Ulfuse:w:0x62:m -Uhfuse:w:0x59:m -Uefuse:w:0xff:m -i960
```

How can I bring my micro to life?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disabling the reset means game over for serial programming because it is used to enter ISP mode.

ATmega without reset can be accessed only by a programmer which can do high-voltage parallel programming, such as the AVR Dragon. If that micro is soldered in a circuit, it is highly inconvenient method and usually not worth the effort.

Comment: How come there is no information about this in datasheet?